# Ejabberd TLS not working and retruns error "no match of right hand side value {error,no_certfile}"

Tags: ssl, ejabberd, lets-encrypt

I have installed the Ejabberd on EC2 instance and it is working properly however the TLS is not working and `wss://` returns error, I checked the logs and following is the error message

```
[error] CRASH REPORT:
  crasher:
    initial call: ejabberd_http:init/3
    pid: <0.712.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,no_certfile}
      in function  ejabberd_http:init/3 (ejabberd_http.erl, line 122)
    ancestors: [ejabberd_http_sup,ejabberd_sup,<0.174.0>]
    message_queue_len: 0
    messages: []

SUPERVISOR REPORT:
    supervisor: {local,ejabberd_http_sup}
    errorContext: child_terminated
    reason: {{badmatch,{error,no_certfile}},
             [{ejabberd_http,init,3,[{file,"ejabberd_http.erl"},{line,122}]},
              {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                        [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}
```

I checked the configurations and I am not able to figure out if there is any issue. Following is my configuration

```
hosts:
  - mydomain.com

loglevel: debug

ca_file: /opt/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem

#certfiles:
#  - /opt/ejabberd/conf/server.pem

## If you already have certificates, list them here
# certfiles:
#  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem
#  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem

certfiles:
  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem

listen:
  -
     port: 5280
     ip: "::"
     module: ejabberd_http
     tls: true
     request_handlers:
        /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
        /api: mod_http_api
        /xmpp: ejabberd_http_ws
        /.well-known/acme-challenge: ejabberd_acme
```

Please help to resolve the issue.